# How to get content of List in one line

Tags: vb.net

How do I get content of list to be displayed or stored in one line.

I get the content but in one line each, I need it to be in one line all.

```
Dim ride as string

For Each ride In myListFlight

    Console.WriteLine(ride)

Next
```

Comment: why C# tag if VB example

Comment: `Console.Write()` ommits the line break.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved. C# as I don't want only VB.Net reply to my post, as sometimes people who develop in C# also may know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?

```
Dim ride as string
ride = String.Join(",", ListOfStrings)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the Aggregate linq function.

What aggregate does is combine entries using a Func.  With strings, this can be as simple as:

```
Dim combined as string
combined = myList.Aggregate(Function(byval a, byval b) a & " " & b)
```

With custom classes, it becomes a bit trickier - you usually have to translate to some sort of 'addable' class (such as a string), like:

```
Dim intermediary as IEnumerable(Of string)
intermediary = myList.Select(Function(x) x.ToString())
Dim combined as string
combined = intermediary.Aggregate(... etc ...)
```

(Pardon if the syntax isn't 100% correct.  I'm a C# dev, so my VB-Linq knowledge is a bit rusty.)